# Error al inicio de sesión en un proyecto de un cliente

Tags: php

Un cliente me dio un proyecto para realizar unos cambios anteriormente ya había programado en el solo descargaba base de datos y el proyecto para iniciar.

hice lo de siempre cambio a local

```
$conectors = array(
    'host'  => 'localhost',
    'user'  => 'root',
    'pass'  => '',
    'DB_PV'     => '*******',
);
```

me arrojo este error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_pconnect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\class.mysql.php:38 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\checkLogin.php(11):
>   sql_db->sql_db('localhost', 'root', '', 'covinmx_ventas', true) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(1): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\class.mysql.php on line 38

Estoy descargando `xampp` con la versión 5

¿Tienen alguna sugerencia que podría ser?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHP estás utilizando con XAMPP? La extensión mysql_* fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0. Aunque estés usanod XAMPP 5, podría ser con PHP 7 y por eso recibirías ese error.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con Alvaro, posiblemente estas usando la version erronea de XAMPP. Para estar seguro, yo crearía un archivo _phpinfo.php_ con la linea `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` para verificar que versión de PHP tienes, y si tienes MySQL habilitado, etc.

Comment: era la version de xampp muchas gracias perdon por responder tarde mucho trabajo